# Cannot get array from post variable, server bug?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a select multiple like so:

```
<select multiple name="viewers[]"> ...
```

The value of the select is sent to a php script via ajax as an array.  On my test server this worked fine:

```
$viewers = $_POST['viewers'];

foreach ($viewers as $v)
{
 //loop through array
}
```

I just uploaded the same script to a production server, running the same version of php (5.2.17) , and it fails.  On the production server, $viewers becomes a string with the value "array":

```
print_r($viewers)
//outputs Array
echo $viewers
//outputs Array
```

Is there some php.ini setting that would force php to treat $viewers as an actual array?

UPDATE:

I did var_dump($_REQUEST) on the production server and got:

```
array(8) {
  ["viewers"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "lilamonte"
  }
  ["new_subject"]=>
  string(12) "Test Subject"
```

On the test server, I got:

```
Array(5) {
  ["viewers"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "libothwell"
  }
  ["new_subject"]=>
  string(4) "test"
```

One works, the other does not.

Comment: What is the result of var_dump?

Comment: `echo $viewers` should always output `Array` - if $viewers is an array (and naturally also if it is the string `"Array"`. More information than `print_r` has `var_dump`. Try to use that. Also view source.

Comment: I'd also suggest running a `var_dump` directly on `$_POST['viewers']`

Comment: `var_dump($viewers) = string(5) "Array" ; var_dump($_POST['viewers'] = string(5) "Array"`

Comment: @Judon if the var_dump is "Array" then you've previously reset $viewers to a string. What is the POST data for the request to PHP?

Comment: try this `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

Comment: Are you modifying $_POST anywhere in your code?

Comment: $_REQUEST looks fine. Does your code work if you change the line to say: `$viewers = $_REQUEST['viewers'];`

Comment: @AlexHowansky It does!!!! Thanks for that!  Do you have any idea what causes this?  I's there any way around this, so that I don't have rewrite a bunch of variables?

Comment: I'm still convinced that your _POST is being fiddled with. Perhaps there is some plugin installed on the server that's not on your dev machine? Suhosin maybe?

Comment: Right again, @AlexHowansky!  The remote server has the Suhosin Patch 0.9.7.  Unfortunately, this is is shared hosting and I can't recompile php.  Is there some way to disable it?  Thanks for helping with this...

Answer (score 0):

It was magic quotes causing this problem.  Apparently, another admin had turned them on for some reason.  (I can't think of anything in all of computing - except for maybe IE6 - that has caused me more problems over the years than magic quotes....)

So, php.ini changed to:

`magic_quotes_gpc = Off`